# How to add a key to a graph drawing?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, legend, graph-theory

I have created a graph using `networkx`. When I draw this graph the node labels do not fit (node names can be pretty long), so I have replaced them by numeric indices. The problem with this workaround is that the resulting drawing is harder to interpret as those numbers are meaningless. This is my code:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(['First', 'Second', 'Third'])
G.add_edges_from([('First', 'Second'), ('First', 'Third'), ('Second', 'Third')])
name2num = {name: num + 1 for num, name in enumerate(list(G.nodes))}
H = nx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping=name2num, copy=True)

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
nx.draw(G, ax=ax0, with_labels=True)
nx.draw(H, ax=ax1, with_labels=True)
```

[image: graphs]
My question is: how could I add a key to the drawing on the right?
This is the information I'd like to display:

```
1 - First
2 - Second
3 - Third
```

I tried to add a legend, to no avail:

```py
ax0.legend(list(name2num.values()), list(name2num.keys()))
```

**PS**: I found a number of threads related to my problem. The proposed solutions consist in encoding the node labels through different colors. I'd rather prefer to encode the node labels through numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `ax.legend` you could place a [`text box`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/recipes/placing_text_boxes.html):

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(["First", "Second", "Third"])
G.add_edges_from([("First", "Second"), ("First", "Third"), ("Second", "Third")])
name2num = {name: num + 1 for num, name in enumerate(list(G.nodes))}
H = nx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping=name2num, copy=True)

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
nx.draw(G, ax=ax0, with_labels=True)
nx.draw(H, ax=ax1, with_labels=True)


legend_text = "\n".join(f"{v} - {k}" for k, v in name2num.items())
props = dict(boxstyle="round", facecolor="w", alpha=0.5)
ax1.text(
    1.15,
    0.95,
    legend_text,
    transform=ax1.transAxes,
    fontsize=14,
    verticalalignment="top",
    bbox=props,
)
```

[image: Network figure with text box legend]

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`nx.draw_networkx_labels`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_labels.html) and use the defined dictionary `name2num` to map the labels in the graph on the second axis. Note that you don't need to create a new graph with renamed labels, just plot the same, disabling `with_labels` and instead using the dictionary:

```
name2num = {name: f'{num}-{name}' for num, name in enumerate(list(G.nodes), 1)}
```

With this you'd get:

```
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

posG_renamed = nx.spring_layout(G)

nx.draw(G, ax=ax0, with_labels=True,
       node_size = 2000, node_color='lightblue')

nx.draw(G, pos=posG_renamed, ax=ax1, 
        node_size = 2000, node_color='lightgreen')

nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, posG_renamed, ax=ax1,
                        labels=name2num,
                        font_size=12)
```

[image]